# REST API design - best practice: Link existing child resource

Tags: web-services, rest, http, asp.net-web-api, restful-url

When designing a REST API I understand how entities can be added (`POST`), updated (`PUT`, `PATCH`) and so on. But I’m wondering how to design the endpoint to add existing items to an existing resource?

Here’s an example: Let’s assume we have an API with the resources `Course` and `Student` and following endpoints:

- `http://localhost/students` - `POST` to add a new student
- `http://localhost/courses` - `POST` to add a new course
- `http://localhost/courses/1` - `PUT` to update course with Id 1
- `http://localhost/courses/1/students` - `GET` to list all students from course with Id 1
- `http://localhost/courses/1/students` - `POST` to add a new student to the course with Id 1

The question is, how can I **link** an **existing student** to an **existing course**? To clarify: With "existing" I'm referring to resources that are already in the system, but are not yet linked.

I see following options:

- `http://localhost/courses/1/students` - `PUT` and send the student Id in the body. The arguments to use `PUT` would be that I am "updating" the students resources of the course.
- `http://localhost/courses/1/students` - `POST` and send the student Id in the body. The reason to use `POST` is that I am "adding/creating" a new resource in the course.
- `http://localhost/courses/1/students/2` - `PUT` and send the Id in the URL and nothing in the body.
- `http://localhost/courses/1/students/2` - `POST` and send the Id in the URL and nothing in the body.
- `http://localhost/students/2` - `PUT` or `POST` and send the course Id in the body.
- `http://localhost/students/2/courses/` - `PUT` or `POST` and send the course Id in the body.
- ...

Are there best practices? Any recommendations? Should this be handled via the `courses` or the `students` resource? Should both be possible? Additionally I'm not sure which method to use (`PUT` or `POST`)?

It kind of feels weird to `PUT` or `POST` with nothing in the body. On the other hand, if everything that is in the body is an Id, why not just put it in the URL?

Comment: use PUT request to update student with ID 1 using http://localhost/students/1 and in the body/data being sent, include the existing Course id. Wouldn't that work for you?

Comment: I was thinking of adding the student via the `courses` resource as this seems the “natural way”. But your approach would definitely work too. I’m just wondering what’s the best approach? Maybe both approaches would be appropriate. I will update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I think the key is here:

> `http://localhost/courses/1/students` - `POST` to add a new student to the
>   course with Id 1

Given that you're using `POST` on this `URL` to generically register students into a course, it shouldn't matter whether the student is new or existing. As you said, that can be an implementation detail, like sending the existing student's `ID` in the body.

Answer (score 0):

> The question is, how can I link an existing student to an existing course?

How would you do it as a web site?

The consumer would land on their bookmarked page, and would look around for a link that would say something like "enroll student".  They would follow that link to a form, or a series of forms, that would collect the input data (an identifier for the student, an identifier for the course, and so on).  Then the consumer would submit the form with the required information.

When the web server received the form submitted in the last step, it would update the domain model as a side effect.

Viewed this way, the "resource" isn't the student, or the course, but is *the inbox for enroll student requests*.

Jim Webber, from his talk on REST and Domain Driven Design:

> The web is not your domain, it's a document management system.  All the HTTP verbs apply to the document management domain. URIs do NOT map onto domain objects - that violates encapsulation.  Work (ex: issuing commands to the domain model) is a side effect of managing resources.

You POST a message to the inbox resource, and as a side effect whatever necessary changes to student or course, happen in your domain.

So the approach you should take to designing URI is;

1. imagine the design of the web site, and the protocol that the consumer would use to interact with it
2. figure out the semantics of each stage of the protocol
3. apply your local URI spelling conventions to that semantic, to determine the identifier for each resource